# match a variable with at least one value in an array - php

Tags: php

I have one variable that comes from a database.
I then want to check whether that value is the same of one of the values in an array.
If the variable matches one of the array values, then I want to print nothing, and if the variable does not match one of the array values, then I want to print something.
This is the code I have been trying without luck, I know that ***contains*** is not valid code, but that is the bit I cannot find any info for:

```
<?php
$site = getStuff(); 
$codes = array('value2', 'value4');
if ($codes contains $site)
{
echo "";
}
else
{
echo "something";
?>
```

So if the database would return value1 for $site, then the code should print "something" because value1 is not in the array.

Comment: Look up [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) in the PHP manual

Answer (score 3):

The function you are looking for is `in_array`.

```
if(in_array($site, array('value2', 'value4')))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!in_array($site,$codes)) {
    echo "something";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To provide another use way to do what the other answers suggest you can use a ternary if

```
echo in_array($site, $codes)?"":"something";
```

Comment: Thanks guys! for helping out a novice